# Biobjective optimisation, pareto non-domination

Tags: optimization, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, decision-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Ok, so, I have a function $f_I(y_1, y_2) = \max\{\alpha y_1 + (1-\alpha)y_2:\alpha\in[\alpha_{min},\alpha_{max}]\}$ that I'm trying to minimise, and I'm asked to find, amongst a set of vectors $y$, the vectors that aren't Pareto-dominated.

Except... I have no idea what a non-Pareto-dominated vector is in this case.

And yes, that's really all I have to go on. The instructions are on [this link](http://www-desir.lip6.fr/~spanjaard/cours/mini-projetMADMC.pdf) (it's a pdf in French). I'm told that a vector is non-dominated if there is no other vector that strictly dominates it (regardless of the interval $I$), but I don't know what that condition entails.

Um... help?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking when you wrote: " I'm asked to find, amongst a set of vectors y, the vectors that aren't Pareto-dominated." $y$ Pareto-dominates $\hat y$ iff $y_i\ge \hat y_i$ for all $i$ and $y_j> \hat y_j$ for some $j$.

Comment: Yeah, the problem's description wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it appears what the problem description meant was exactly that $y$ is non-Pareto-dominated if there is no $y'$ such that $y'$ Pareto-dominates $y$.